# How to install anbox in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, anbox

I am a lubuntu user using lubuntu 20.04 (focal fossa) and wanted to run some of my favorite android apps in anbox. I tried the following code but it is giving error.`sudo apt install anbox-module-dkms`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package anbox-modules-dkms
```

And I can't install the kernel modules.

Comment: I don't think that this a duplicate of that post, the OP did not try to install the snap, they tried the repo version and this issue is a wrong package name.

Comment: I concur. Also all the answers on the redirection are about older ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got that package name from but it does not exist, to install anbox from the repos just use

```
sudo apt install anbox
```

It should install any required modules automatically.

Comment: what should I do now.

Comment: @Lubuntuuser What do you want to do? To run it you either find it in your application launcher or type `anbox` in to a terminal.