# Anbox not starting

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, android, anbox

[image: Error when trying to start anbox]I have installed Anbox using:

```
 sudo apt install anbox
```

As per [this answer on Ask Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254987/how-to-install-anbox-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Anbox tries to start but will not. I am using Lubuntu 20.04.

```
martyn@martyn-hp255g1notebookpc:~$ anbox launch -- package=org.anbox.appmgr --
component=org.anbox.appmgr.AppViewActivity [2022-01-14 15:23:07] [daemon.cpp:61@Run] Application manager
service is not running yet
martyn@martyn-hp255g1notebookpc:~$ anbox system-info version: 0.0~git20191115-1build1-Ubuntu
cpu:
arch: x86
brand: AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics
features: - aes
- sse4_1
- sse4_2
- avx
OS:
name: Ubuntu
version: 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
snap-based: false
kernel:
version: Linux version 5.11.0-46-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-010) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #51-20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 06:51:40 UTC 2022
binder: false
ashmem: true
graphics:
egl:
vendor: Mesa Project
version: 1.5
extensions:
- Various
gles2:
vendor: AMD
vendor: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.0.3
extensions:
- Various
martyn@martyn-hp255g1notebookpc:~$ anbox session-manager
[ 2022-01-14 15:23:36] [session_manager.cpp:133@operator()] Failed to start as either binder or ashmem kernel drivers are not loaded martyn@martyn-hp255g1notebookpc:~$
```

Comment: How do I extract ashmem and biinder into /usr/ from anbox master.zip PLEASE

Comment: I am trying to do this: (https://superuser.com/questions/1209153/how-do-i-install-ashmem-or-binder#1415872) I got permission denied when attempting to extract anbox-master.zip to usr.